# How to customize one column and display remaining in activeadmin

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, activeadmin

I am using Active admin gem in my rails app. I added resources book which has 20 columns, now i need to customize only one column and print the remaining as it is. I tried below code

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
 index do
  column :description do 
    raw "<a class='view_description button'>View Description</a>"
  end
 end
end
```

but which hides all the columns and show only description. Any help will be useful.

Comment: you need to list all the rows if you start with customizations like so https://github.com/phoet/on_ruby/blob/master/app/admin/users.rb#L19

Comment: its hell for big table then , thanks for the link.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If you specify an index block, you need to put all the columns that you want to show, because you are replacing the "default" behaviour.

In your case, you need to add the other 19 columns with something like:

```rb
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
 index do
  column :one
  column :two
  column :three
  column :name
  column :title
  column :pages
  column :description do 
    raw "<a class='view_description button'>View Description</a>"
  end
 end
end
```

Comment: just one tip, better to use `link_to 'View Description', root_path, class: 'view_description button'` rather raw link

Answer (score 45):

How about this?

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  index do
    columns_to_exclude = ["name"]
    (Book.column_names - columns_to_exclude).each do |c|
      column c.to_sym
    end
    column :description do 
      raw "<a class='view_description button'>View Description</a>"
    end
   end
end
```

Comment: Was searching the internet everywhere for this!  Thank you!

Comment: This is the best answer in StackOverflow.

Comment: But in this case link(i.e. href) which shows by default on some columns i.e. referenced columns is not preserving. How to get that as well, without adding individual columns with link_to method?

Answer (score 10):

In my case, I want only rename the one column, 
I have done this way ->

```
index do
    column :one
    column :two  
    ....
    column "View Description", :description # This will change you column label **description** to **View Description**
end
```

Answer (score 4):

I was curious about this question too. Here is what I found

```
  index do
    column :id
    active_admin_config.resource_columns.each do |attribute|
      column attribute
    end
  end
```

https://github.com/activeadmin/activeadmin/blob/5dbf9b690302ecb4ba0c0ce59b2fb4735c88b35c/lib/active_admin/views/index_as_table.rb#L261

Comment: MVP answer right here... This also works in `show do` etc... This is a good way to retrieve all the columns using active_admin internals

Answer (score 3):

This also works when you want add or customize just a single column to the default list (based on an association which is for a belongs_to).

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  index do
    column :publisher do |book|
      book.publisher.name
    end
    Book.column_names.each do |c|
      column c.to_sym
    end

  end
end
```

Answer (score 2):

In General, this is quite easy..

```
ActiveAdmin.register Book do
  index do
    (Book.column_names - ["column_to_customize"]).each do |c|
      column c.to_sym
    end
    column :column_to_customize do 
      raw "<a class='view_description button'>View Description</a>"
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: But in this case link(i.e. href) which shows by default on some columns i.e. referenced columns is not preserving. How to get that as well, without adding individual columns with link_to method?

Answer (score 0):

This is pretty accurate to mimic original behavior in a generic way:

```
index do
  selectable_column

  Book.column_names.each do |c|
    # Filter foreign IDs and counter caches
    column c.to_sym unless c.ends_with?('_id') || c.ends_with?('_count')
  end

  Book.reflect_on_all_associations(:belongs_to).map(&:name).each do |association|
    column association
  end

  # Whatever custom thing you want

  actions
end
```